# ActionBarDrawerToggle can't find its activity

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have finally managed to compile appcompat-v7 and now when my application start, it throws the following exception:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.Project1.MainActivity$1

This is the line where it throws that:

```
package com.example.Project1;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity
    {
      private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
      private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
     ...
      drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,
                    R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close)
```

This is the package in the Manifest:

```
 package="com.example.Project1"
```

It also contains MainActivity.

Comment: What package is your `MainActivity.java` in and what have you put in the `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: try to change this with MainActivtiy.this.

Comment: post the whole manifest please

Comment: You forgot to declare your MainActivity in your Manifest.xml file.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the exception refers to `MainActivity$1`, which is an anonymous inner class within MainActivity, and not MainActivity itself.  I suspect it's referring to your ActionBarDrawerToggle, and that your code continues as:

```
drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,
    R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
        ...
    }

    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I encountered this same exception when I migrated from ActionBarDrawerToggle [v4](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html) (which is deprecated) to [v7](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html).  In the end, I found the exception was caused by referencing two different v7 support jars (one of which didn't include the v7 ActionBarDrawerToggle) in my project.  I resolved it by

1. removing references to each jar (in Eclipse: right click project > Properties > Java Build Path)
2. importing `android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat` as an Eclipse project
3. adding that project as a library to my Android project (right click project > Properties > Android > Library > Add...)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, NoClassDefFoundError means you forgot to define your activity in your manifest.
This is how a simple manifest should look like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.Project1">

    <application
        android:name=".Project1">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Does your manifest include the `<activity>` tag and its content ?
You can check here for more information : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html